# Issue with sherlock actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

Image as seen in ICS
[image]

Where as when run in Gingerbread
[image]

XML code for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/background"
 android:id="@+id/homelayout" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/homepageLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:alpha="255"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any reason for such strange behavior?

Comment: The issue is being observed if the icon is present, if I remove the icon, the text is displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is observed only when you dynamically request for the actionbar from the code.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

If you do it using styles, this problem is not seen.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in your ImageView. I don't know how you use your XML, but by the looks of it you might also want to change te same parameters in the LinearLayout to "wrap_content". Now you are telling the ImageView to (probably) fill the whole area.

// Alex